# Where can I get backcopies of the weekly newsletter?

Tags: support, newsletter

I don't really want to subscribe to the weekly newsletter (I've got enough email) but I would like to flick through some back issues. Are they available online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from pestering longtime subscribers to forward their back copies to you, there's no way to get old newsletters.

Also, the "Greatest hits" and "Can you answer these?" sections of the newsletter vary from person to person, so two versions of the same newsletter typically aren't identical.